# Automation of a web page using Pupeteer does not go through

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

When I am on a particular website where I need to initiate a chat and then click on a popup and then once the chat box appear the automation should have at least 4 line conversation with the agent on the other side and then the automation should close the chat popup using a dedicated close button on the chat box and select few radio box selection and then click on submit and then start the same thing again.

I was able to automate till the code is able to look for the chat initiate popup icon however can not click on it to initiate the chat.

PS. I am amateur in Coding.

Comment: Can you post your current code? So we can check what you've done so far. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `page.click("your-button-selector")`.

You can read about this in the Pippeteer API documentation: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options

Comment: I am using it however it is not clicking it.

Comment: I am using the above however it is not selecting the element of that page and popup the chat button

Comment: You can also try this: ```await page.$eval('#tcWatchTVCare', el => el.click());```. However, it is weird that the first method did not work, are you sure that the selector is correct?

Comment: I will try this, Yes the selector is correct, you can email me on if you can email me on moja.joota@gmail.com then it would be really great Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, What I had to do was pur some delay as it was trying to click on it before the image is loaded on the page

Comment: Yep! Its working awesome now, Just trying to figure out how to select the radio buttons before I can submit the from in the page. If you know and see this before I get it working please let me know.

Comment: You can try: ```await page.$eval("input[type='radio'][value='your-desired-value']", el => el.click())```

Comment: Now there is one more challenge.

Comment: `<span class="agentId">Adam:&nbsp;</span>`  

This is one of the code line in the webpage and I want to run the automation only if the name of the agent is Adam. 

There is no unique selector or identifier of the agent name in the body, I have to somehow get the name of the agent from the span and then put a if else loop. How do I pull the name of the agent from the Span ?
 A piece of code will do amazing if you can share it

Comment: You can try: ```const agentName = await page.$eval("span.agentId", el => el.textContent)```